# Issue with menu roll out with click or hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am having issues on getting my menu content to pop out when a user clicks or hovers the hamburger menu. Angular is the base of my app and I have some in view javascript and css to get this to work, but not getting desired results. My screenshot showing this corner is here:

[image]
My code is all in here:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="mbapp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Cloud + Enterprise // Moneyball Tools</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

    <!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/vendor.css -->
    <!-- bower:css -->
    <!-- run `gulp inject` to automatically populate bower styles dependencies -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:css({.tmp/serve,src}) styles/app.css -->
    <!-- inject:css -->
    <!-- css files will be automatically insert here -->
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
    <base href="/">  
    <link href="app/styles/mbapp.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
 <style type="text/css">
    li > .sideCont > a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    li > .sideCont > li a: hover {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: inherit;
    }    

    .menu_items_toggle {
        opacity: 1 !important;
        top: 100% !important;
    }

    #menu {
        position: relative;
    }
    #menu_items {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0%;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    .menu_items_toggle {
        opacity: 1 !important;
        top: 100% !important;
    }
</style>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: #f5faff;">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="font-family: Segoe UI; padding: 0;">
        <div id="menu" style="background-color: #002F33; min-height:50px;">
            <span id="span_img_container" class="navIcon" style="width: 50px; border-right-style: solid 1px #939393;"><img id="menu_img" src="assets/images/icon_hamburger.png"></span>
            <div id="menu_items">
                <a href="https://www.moneyball.ms/">Moneyball Website</a>
                <br>
                <a href="https://www.tools.moneyball.ms/">Moneyball Tool</a>
                <br>
                <a href="https://msit.microsoftstream.com/channel/8a4a7740-855b-4c52-912c-c97fb714a0a6">Moneyball Stream Channel</a> 
                <br>
            </div>
            <span style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 22px; padding-left:20px; padding-top: 21px;">Moneyball Tool</span>> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 tabNav">
            <ul class="tabTitle">
                <p>Project tools</p>
                <li class="tabCont"><a href="#/home">Welcome</a></li>
                <li class="tabCont"><a href="#">Experiments</a></li>
                <li class="tabCont"><a href="#">Interview Notes</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="tabTitle">
                <p>Hypothesis worksheets</p>
                <li class="tabCont"><a href="/#/steps">Problem phase</a></li>
                <li class="tabCont"><a href="/#/solutionHyp">Solution phase</a></li>
                <li class="tabCont"><a href="#">Service phase</a></li>
                <li class="tabCont"><a href="#">Growth phase</a></li>                
            </ul>            
        </div>
        <div ui-view>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //make a refernce to the container that holds all your links
        var menu_item_container = document.getElementById("menu_items")

        //This function will show/hide menu options if image is clicked on
        function clicker() {
            menu_item_container.classList.toggle('menu_items_toggle');
            console.log(menu_item_container.classList.contains('menu_items_toggle'))
        }
        console.log(document.getElementById("span_img_container"));
        document.getElementById("menu_img").addEventListener('click', clicker)
    </script>

    <!-- build:js(src) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <!-- run `gulp inject` to automatically populate bower script dependencies -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js({.tmp/serve,.tmp/partials,src}) scripts/app.js -->
    <!-- inject:js -->
    <!-- js files will be automatically insert here -->
    <!-- endinject -->

    <!-- inject:partials -->
    <!-- angular templates will be automatically converted in js and inserted here -->
    <!-- endinject -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pretty sure the style tag should be inside the head.

Comment: @Sandro - good catch, I fixed that in this, but in my code, it is in the head. Problem still exist. On top of that, when the user clicks on the hamburger menu, it acts as a link rather than popping out the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your menu lies on top of your "hamburger menu".
This happens because the only elements that are not clickable are those that are set to `display: none;` or `pointer-events: none;`.

You can fix this as follows:

```
#menu_items.menu_items_toggle {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Notice how I added the id (#menu_items) to the selector so that the CSS selector specificity is higher without adding the `!important`.

To your menu_items styles you have to add `display: none;`.

```
#menu_items {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: this helps and works if I comment out the div with the class tabNav. Seems it will not show about that div even with me messing with the z-index. Thoughts?

Comment: it seems to work here: http://codepen.io/Spreadyy/pen/dOZomY Maybe you need to set  a background-color?